Are Eidolons Proficient in Perception?
Checking through the rules for summoner eidolons, I couldn't find any mention of them having a proficiency like training in Perception by default. The online version of the rules don't seem to differ from the Secrets of Magic book on this, and otherwise it seems that they'd be one of the only cases where a creature isn't trained in Perception.
At 3rd level summoners gain Shared Vigilance which increases both character's proficiency to expert in Perception, so this would only impact eidolons for summoners at levels 1 and 2. Other characters that take the Summoner Dedication share their Perception proficiency with their eidolon to avoid the issue.

From a strict reading of the rules, no
Reviewing the rules for the Summoner, you're correct that nothing appears to grant eidolons Trained proficiency with Perception until Shared Vigilance. The eidolon rules state that the eidolon gains your skill proficiencies, but it states nothing about Perception specifically.
It's hard to prove a negative and likely the design intent was for eidolons to match their proficiency for Perception to the summoner, but Perception is not listed anywhere in the Skills section and its omission suggests it's a wholly separate thing.
There is some rules support for the notion that Eidolons aren't proficient in Perception found in the Legacy version of the Perception rules (and as found by brandon in the Remaster too), which states:

Nearly all creatures are at least trained in Perception, so you will almost always add a proficiency bonus to your Perception modifier.

As such, there is a statement within the rules that not everything will be trained in Perception.

The fact that at level 3 eidolons go straight to Expert suggests that they are Trained before, it just slipped somehow from the text

@András I agree and would probably house rule that they start as Trained. But as I said, this is a strict reading of the rules, not necessarily a common sense one.
